# How to store use triple-quoted backtick strings with marked.js

Tags: javascript, javascript-marked

I'm using marked.js to render code that we want to store (ultimately as JSON). However, the I can't get triple-back-ticked convention to render correctly. I'm sure user error on my part but how would I to get the following to work?

````
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
let str = marked.parse("here is the body of arguments ```\n\nclass User\n  def say_my_name\n  puts 'my name'\n  end\nend```");
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = str;
</script>
````

which renders for me like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is

> ````markdown
> here is the body of arguments ```
>
> class User
>   def say_my_name
>   puts 'my name'
>   end
> end```
> ````

But that is not valid. The code fences should always be on a new line:

````js
let str = marked.parse("here is the body of arguments \n```\n\nclass User\n  def say_my_name\n  puts 'my name'\n  end\nend\n```");
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = str;
````

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the newlines mixed up around the first trio of backticks:

````js
let str = marked.parse("here is the body of arguments\n ```\nclass User\n  def say_my_name\n  puts 'my name'\n  end\nend```");

document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = str;
````

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

See how it's monospace now?

Comment: You'll probably want another newline before the closing backticks too otherwise it all gets rendered on a single line ignoring the newlines in the code block